# How do I create a dynamic field on a front-end form with the Sprout Forms plugin?

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I have a job listing channel. I want to create a form on the front-end that has all the jobs that are created in the channel inside of it. I'm using the Sprout Forms plugin, but when I create a custom plugin that creates a new field type. I get the error that this field isn't meant to be used on the front-end.

Has anyone encountered this situation? Have any recommendations? Or am I going about it all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sprout Forms needs to know how a field should render on the front-end. By default it supports several common fields, but you will need to add support for custom fields on your own.  It sounds like you've got your field created and working, so you'll just need to add [Sprout Forms front-end field support](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/customization/custom-front-end-fields).

Adding support on the front-end is very similar to how you added support for your field in the Craft control panel. If you want to see several examples of custom fields adding front-end field support for Sprout Forms, take a look at the [Sprout Fields](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/fields) plugin.